Unnesting lists in a Python Polars column generates a SchemaError
I am new in Polars.
I am trying to use the .unnest() method on a column in a Polars data frame.
In the example attached below I generate the column "processed" as Lists of Strings.
The strings are made by a sequence and a percentage, converted in string. My purpose is to unnest all the lists in the column's cells and create two other columns, one for the sequence and the other for the respective percentage.
Although I already used the unnest method in an identical case (that worked), now it does not work.
I think that there is some issue related to the generation of the "processed" column.
However, I cannot figure out what is the issue.
My code:
import polars as pl
from functools import reduce

# Function to MAP the peptide inside the protein sequence.
# Convert the peptide sequence in dashes inside the original protein sequence.
def replace_peptide(protein_sequence, peptide):
    return protein_sequence.replace(peptide, '-' * len(peptide))

# Function to COLLAPSE all the dashed protein sequences to generate a final sequence 
# that reports a "-" for each letter in the peptide sequence that map in the protein sequence.
def combine_sequences(seq1, seq2):
    return ''.join(['-' if a == '-' or b == '-' else a for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2)])

# Function to apply the mapping procedure for each row in the dataframe.
def process_row(row):
    protein_sequence = row['sequence']
    protein_sequence_len = len(protein_sequence)
    peptides = row['peptide']
    modified_sequences = [replace_peptide(protein_sequence, peptide) for peptide in peptides]
    final_sequence = reduce(combine_sequences, modified_sequences)
    coverage = str('{:.2f}%').format(final_sequence.count('-')/protein_sequence_len*100)
    return final_sequence, coverage
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# Generate the data frame
coverage_fasta=pl.DataFrame({"protein_id": ["A0A024RBG1", "A0A087X1C5", "A0A0B4J2F0"],
                             "sequence": ["MMKFKPNQTRTYDREGFKKRAACLCFRSEQEDEVLLVSSSRYPDQWIVPG",
                                          "MGLEALVPLAMIVAIFLLLVDLMHRHQRWAARYPPGPLPLPGLGNLLHVD",
                                            "MFRRLTFAQLLFATVLGIAGGVYIFQPVFEQYAKDQKELKEKMQLVQESE"],
                             "peptide": [["MMKFKPNQT", "FKKRAA", "SSSRYPDQ"],
                                         ["EALVPLAM", "AQLLFATVLGIAG", "QPVFEQYAKDQ"], 
                                         ["RRLTFAQLL", "LTFAQLLFATVLGIAGG", "QYAKDQKEL"]
                            ]}
)

# Generate the column that contain a list made by the protein sequences dashed and their coverage percentage.
coverage_fasta = coverage_fasta.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["sequence", "peptide"]).map_elements(lambda row: process_row(row),
                                                    return_dtype=pl.List(pl.String())
                                                    ).alias("processed"))
display(coverage_fasta)

# Command to unnest the lists in the "processed" column. 
# The purpose is to have the dashed sequences in one column and the percentage of coverage in another one.
coverage_fasta = coverage_fasta.with_columns(pl.col("processed")).unnest("processed")
display(coverage_fasta)

The output:

Please can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

unnest is for structs but processed is list - are you trying to explode/flatten the lists?

As already mentioned in the comments, pl.DataFrame.unnest is used to unnest struct columns into their fields. Your function map_elements creates a column of type list[str] instead.
You could adapt your function to return a struct with fields final_sequence and coverage (and adapt the return_dtype instead).
def process_row(row):
    ...
    return {"final_sequence": final_sequence, "coverage": coverage}

coverage_fasta = coverage_fasta.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["sequence", "peptide"]).map_elements(
        lambda row: process_row(row), 
        return_dtype=pl.Struct([
            pl.Field("final_sequence", pl.String()), 
            pl.Field("coverage", pl.String())
        ])
    ).alias("processed")
)

Then, unnesting should work as expected.
pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(16)
pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars(128)

coverage_fasta.unnest("processed")

shape: (3, 5)
┌────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────┐
│ protein_id ┆ sequence          ┆ peptide           ┆ final_sequence    ┆ coverage │
│ ---        ┆ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---      │
│ str        ┆ str               ┆ list[str]         ┆ str               ┆ str      │
╞════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════╡
│ A0A024RBG1 ┆ MMKFKPNQTRTYDREG… ┆ ["MMKFKPNQT", "F… ┆ ---------RTYDREG… ┆ 46.00%   │
│ A0A087X1C5 ┆ MGLEALVPLAMIVAIF… ┆ ["EALVPLAM", "AQ… ┆ MGL--------IVAIF… ┆ 16.00%   │
│ A0A0B4J2F0 ┆ MFRRLTFAQLLFATVL… ┆ ["RRLTFAQLL", "L… ┆ MF--------------… ┆ 56.00%   │
└────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────┘

